# PocketSVG framework

Tags: ios, swift, svg

I want to show SVG image and also parse that image. I am using Pocket SVG framework for this. While using this framework, my SVG image in showing on view but it is black color filled. Why it is behaving like this?
Code for this:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ENCLAVE", withExtension: "svg")! let svgImageView = SVGImageView.init(contentsOf: url)
 svgImageView.frame = view.bounds svgImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit 
view.addSubview(svgImageView)
```

And i am using Pocket SVG Framework
It is showing like this.
[image]

Comment: Because the paths have no `fill`? Can you please edit your question and add the resulting SVG?

Comment: @enxaneta Path has no fill? Meaning of this? Can you please elaborate this.

Comment: The default value for the `fill` attribute is "black".

Comment: @enxaneta Some SVG file is showing properly but this SVG is showing black. Why so?

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ENCLAVE", withExtension: "svg")!
        let svgImageView = SVGImageView.init(contentsOf: url)
        svgImageView.frame = view.bounds
        svgImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(svgImageView)

Comment: You should add this to your question. However I wanted to see the resulting SVG.

Comment: @enxaneta I added code in my question. And resulting SVG is also showing up there in question as an image. Please see there.